# Fix If/Else function so it only runs if variable is True

Tags: php, function

I have been trying to get the developers of an app I use to fix an error that makes their app unuseable, but so far its unresolved and so I am wondering if I can get any help here to fix it.

This is the current code:-

```
function vpc_apply_wad_discount_on_option( $product_id, $option_price ) {

        global $wad_discounts;
        $new_option_price = $option_price;
        if ( class_exists( 'Wad' ) ) {
        foreach ( $wad_discounts[ 'product' ] as $discount_id => $discount_obj ) {
            if ( $discount_obj->is_applicable( $product_id ) ) {
            $new_option_price = $option_price - $discount_obj->get_discount_amount( $option_price );
            }
        }
        }
        return $new_option_price;
    }
```

This code was returning 8800 duplicate queries as its checking every single one. I only want it to loop through that foreach if another variable `$affectsprice` is true, this is where I've got to, but I'm not a developer and although the code is working its still returning 5,900 duplicates, so its not right.

```
    function vpc_apply_wad_discount_on_option( $product_id, $option_price ) {
        global $wad_discounts;
        $affectsprice=0;
        $new_option_price = $option_price;
        if (( class_exists( 'Wad' ) ) && (!$affectsprice)){
            foreach ( $wad_discounts[ 'product' ] as $discount_id => $discount_obj ) {
               if  ($discount_obj->is_applicable( $product_id ))
                        {
                $new_option_price = $option_price - $discount_obj->get_discount_amount( $option_price );
                }
                }}
        else{
        $new_option_price = $option_price;
```

Comment: You never set `$affectsprice`

Comment: thanks I just corrected that, its still returning 5900 duplicates :(

Comment: It's still always false. How do you see it being changed?

Comment: I just put it there to test the code.  This is a configurator where some options affect the price but 99.9% of them dont.  At the moment they loop through every singe option item to check if there is a price to change.  I want them to bypass all of them, except if I check a radio button to say, the option items, inside this option type do have prices in.

Comment: `&& $affectsprice)`  Don'e use `!` that turns `true` into `false`.  And since you set it to `0` it is always `false`.

Comment: What do you mean by "duplicates" and "duplicate queries"?  All your items seem to be coming from `global $wad_discounts` (seriously using globals!). We don't really know what `is_applicable` does. In any case, it's unclear what you're trying to do with `$affectsprice`, since it's hard-wired to `0`. Also, your function is _looping through all items_ but only returns one value? If the first sample really is the current code, then _may I suggest looking into migrating to something more coherently coded_. Would be easier to modify.

Comment: Thanks Markus, yes I came to the same opinion, I found even more errors with their code today when testing, it just goes on and on! I contacted another provider of a discount plugin and have asked them to quote me to modify it to my needs.  I have an older program from the same company that works great! They've butchered it and added in so many "features" their current version doesnt actually work.